# Run script on SSH login to server

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, tcsh, csh

I'm trying to work out how to get SSH to run a script before passing a shell to me. The reason for this is that I will be logging into shared users on many boxes and I want my own configuration when I log in. It would not be appropriate to put my own environment variables and aliases into `.cshrc`, not least because of the number of different users on different boxes that I will be logging in to.

So let's say I have my script with various `alias` and `setenv` commands at `/home/adam/my_script` and I want it to be sourced when I log in.

I've tried using:

```
ssh user@server1 'source /home/adam/my_script; tcsh'
ssh user@server1 '. /home/adam/my_script; tcsh'
```

and also this:

```
ssh user@server1 /home/adam/my_script
ssh user@server1 'csh -c /home/adam/my_script'
```

when `tcsh` (without an ampersand) is at the bottom of `my_script`, but no combination works as you expect. Either the environment variables and aliases don't exist, or the shell will behave strangely, like there is no line input prompt.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would think this should work: `ssh -t user@server1 'source /home/adam/my_script; tcsh'` -- add `-t`

Comment: The environment variables work but it appears that the aliases don't. I guess they're not inherited by child shells?

Comment: You'd have to check your tcsh man page. What I do in a similar situation is edit the .bashrc to add a function that sources my config script. So I log in, type `jackman` and I'm set up.